# Printing repeated watermark background image inside an html table

Tags: printing, html-table, watermark

I have a web page that contains a repeated background image, but when i try to print the page using ctrl + p its showing page print preview without background.

Could you please tell me how to force to print the background?

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qzw639e4/5/

- the system has more than one language, therefore, it's necessary to create the image dynamically. It's the reason that I am using a html canvas for this.

```
function AppViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.items = ko.observableArray([]);

  for(var i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    var item ={
      id: i,
      description: 'test'+i,
      cost: i*5,
      price: i*8,
      PriceToCustomer: i*10
    }

    self.items.push(item);
  }

  self.print = function(){
    window.print();
  }

  var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = "500";
  canvas.height = "400";
  ctx.font = '15pt Arial';
  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(100, 400);
  ctx.rotate(-45 * Math.PI / 180);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;
  var rText = "This text must be a repeated background image.";
  ctx.fillText(rText, 0, 0);
  ctx.restore();
  $('tbody').css('background-image', 'url(' + ctx.canvas.toDataURL() + ') ');
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested the solution below and the bg was correctly printed by the browser:

```
        <body>
    <div id="background">
  <p id="bg-text"> Sample Background</p>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
  Content of the page goes here.....................
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
    <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
  <br/>
<p>HI TO EVERBODY </p>

    </div>
#background{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
    background:white;
    display:block;
    min-height:50%; 
    min-width:50%;
    color:yellow;
}

#content{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}

#bg-text
{   margin: -900px;
    color:lightgrey;
    font-size:60px;
    transform:rotate(300deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(300deg);
}
```

https://codepen.io/YuvarajTana/pen/auiqx

The example is not a repeated background, but with some adjustments maybe it becomes suitable for your need.